# A problem with property of normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be real unitary vector space such and $F$ be a normal operator on $X$ (i.e. $AA^*=A^*A$). Suppose that for some $x,y \in X$ not simultanuously $0$ and $a,b\in \mathbb R$:
$$
F(x)=ax-by,
$$
$$
F(y)=bx+ay.
$$
I try to prove that

$$
F^*(x)=ax+by,
$$
$$
F^*(y)=-bx+ay.
$$

I want to do its but without complexification.

Edit.

I assume additionally that $b\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let $G=\dfrac{1}{b}(F-aId)$. Notice that $G$ is normal too.

Next, let $V=\text{span}\{x,y\}$ and notice that $G(x)=-y$ and $G(y)=x$.

Thus, $G^2(x)=-x$ and $G^2(y)=-y$. Therefore $G^2(v)=-v$, for every $v\in V$.

So $0=\langle (G^2+Id)(v),(G^2+Id)(v)\rangle=\langle (G^*)^2+Id(v),(G^*)^2+Id(v)\rangle$, because $G$ is normal.

Therefore $(G^*)^2+Id(v)=0$ and $(G^*)^2(v)=-v$ for every $v\in V$.

Next, $(G^*)^2G^2(v)=v$ for every $v\in V$.

Since $G$ is normal then $(G^*)^2G^2(v)=(G^*G)^2(v)=v$, for every $v\in V$.

Thus, $0=(G^*G)^2-Id(v)=(G^*G+Id)(G^*G-Id)(v)$. Now, $(G^*G+Id)$ is a positive definite self-adjoint linear transformation which implies $(G^*G-Id)(v)=0$, for every $v\in V$.

Finally, $x=G^*G(x)=G^*(-y)$ and $y=G^*G(y)=G^*(x)$, which implies $F^*(y)=-bx+ay$
and $F^*(x)=ax+by$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, should be $F(y)=bx+ay$.

Comment: @user172903 I will edit this post. I realize how to avoid this problem of proving that $F|_V$ is normal.

Comment: @user172903 See if you agree with me.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you once again.

Comment: @user172903 you are welcome.